# Suma de datos de una columna

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, datatable

Tengo una tabla, que integra el plugin de datatable, esta tabla tiene una columna llamada trabajadores totales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo, mi programa esta escrito en laravel.

```
                    <tbody>

                    @foreach ($reportes as $reporte)
                    <tr style="text-align: center;">
                        <td><a href="{{route('reports.view' , ['id' => $reporte->id])}}">{{$reporte->id}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->user->name}} {{$reporte->user->surname}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->empresa->nombre}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->calificacionA}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->calificacionB}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->tEventuales}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->tPlanta}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->tEventuales + $reporte->tPlanta}}</td>

                        <td>{{($reporte->calificacionA + $reporte->calificacionB)/2}}</td>

                    </tr>
                    @endforeach

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Total: 348</td>
                    </tr>



                </tbody>
```

Esta es la funcion que hace la llamada al modelo Report

```
    public function index(){

    $reportes = Report::all();

    return view('reports.index', [
        'reportes' => $reportes,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: la suma de todos los valores va debajo de todos ellos? podrias colocar un html minimo de cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: @Bryro así es va debajo de ellos, acabo de editar la pregunta, agregando lo que me pediste. Mi duda es como se podría hacer si es un datatable y los valores estarán cambiando depende la búsqueda del usuario. No se si me llego a explicar al 100%.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos donde sacas los datos/llamada a los modelos? Creo que ese calcula debería ser hecho en el controlador

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido acabo de poner el código donde se llama al modelo, en la pregunta, una disculpa.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
// creamos una variable que almacenara nuestra suma
@php $total=0 @endphp
@foreach ($reportes as $reporte)
// agregamos la suma a total
@php $total += $reporte->tEventuales + $reporte->tPlanta  @endphp
<tr style="text-align: center;">
    <td><a href="{{route('reports.view' , ['id' => $reporte->id])}}">{{$reporte->id}}</a></td>
    <td>{{$reporte->user->name}} {{$reporte->user->surname}}</td>
    <td>{{$reporte->empresa->nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{$reporte->calificacionA}}</td>
    <td>{{$reporte->calificacionB}}</td>
    <td>{{$reporte->tEventuales}}</td>
    <td>{{$reporte->tPlanta}}</td>
    <td>{{$reporte->tEventuales + $reporte->tPlanta}}</td> //Este es el campo que deseo hacer la suma
    <td>{{($reporte->calificacionA + $reporte->calificacionB)/2}}</td> 
</tr>
@endforeach

<tr>
//imprimos el el valor de nuestra variable total
<td colspan="7">Total: {{$total}}</td>
</tr>
```

**si quieres sumar con datatable.js es:**

> **nota:** debes agregar un tfoot

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total;
  var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

            total = api
            .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
            }, 0 );
          $("#total").text(total);
   }
  });
});
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td class="sum">800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td class="sum">800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
       <td class="sum">800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td class="sum">800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot align="right">
      </tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Acabo de poner tu código, funciono muy bien hace la suma de todos lo valores, solo dos detalles la variable total tuve que imprimirla fuera del datatable ya que daba un error, pero ya fuera funciono correctamente. La segunda es que al filtrar y buscar la suma de los trabajadores sigue igual, no varia depende lo que muestra la pantalla. Podrías darme una idea de como realizar eso? que sea una suma dinámica y no estática.

Comment: no te entiendo del todo filtrar como??? utilizas algun plugins como datatable.js??

Comment: Asi es hermano, estoy utilizando el plugin datable.js .

Comment: y porque tu pregunta fue en php?? deberias formular la preguntar en base a ello eso no es php es javascript y lo que estas pintando no tiene nada que ver.